# SSMS "New Database" option does not appear

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I cannot see the option "New Database" when right click on the database folder, and also when enter to the attach, it also does not appear the option for adding file, just the folder and limited link. Anyone help me about this. Thanks so much

[image]

Comment: Because you *don't* create a database in SSAS like that.

Comment: You've connected to an Analysis Server, not a Database Engine. Click the Connect dropdown to see the two.

Comment: tks so much for your help, I could do it by connecting to the database server of my company on Azure. But if I want to set a server on my computer, how to do it? I tried to connect to my Administrator acc but it's failed.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments you are using SSMS but you have not connected to **SQL Server**, note in your own screenshot:

[image]

You need to connect to SQL Server, you'll then see the *New Database* option:

[image]

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much